# Order columns in CSV file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I am trying to order all columns by column name in a CSV file.
What I have is something like this:

```
name  ,adress  ,mobile-number
Ane   ,USA     ,12121212
Joane ,England ,234234
```

and the output I need is

```
adress ,name  ,mobile-number
USA    ,Ane   ,12121212
England,Joane ,234234
```

The problem is that I have more than three columns, and I don't know the order they come in, but I need to reorder them in ascending order.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know what order they come in? What do you know? How can we know what column to sort on? Do we have to sort on whatever column the "name" header describes? Also, why do you have `name, address` in the input but `address, name` in the output? Is that intentional? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: I think OP wants to sort the columns by name. So columns beginning with A should come first. But it seems the example is wrong since `name` should come after `mobile-number` by that logic. OP can you please clarify/edit the question,

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller (`mlr`) to clean up the excessive whitespace in each field (including in the header), and then to reorder the fields:

```bash
$ mlr --csv clean-whitespace then reorder -f adress,name,mobile-number file
adress,name,mobile-number
USA,Ane,12121212
England,Joane,234234
```

(note that using `reorder -f adress` would move only the `adress` field to the start of the fields, which in this case would have the same effect.)

Or, if you want to order the fields in ascending order according to the way the headings sort:

```bash
$ mlr --csv clean-whitespace then sort-within-records file
adress,mobile-number,name
USA,12121212,Ane
England,234234,Joane
```

Answer (score 1):

What we can do is transpose the columns to rows using the [`rs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rs&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd) utility originating from BSD Unix, then just `sort` the rows (thus, effectively, sorting the columns of the original data), and then transpose again.

**Firstly, note by the way that, in alphabetical order, it's: address, mobile-number, name. M is before N!**

Step by step:

```
$ cat data
name  ,adress  ,mobile-number
Ane   ,USA     ,12121212
Joane ,England ,234234

$ rs -s, -C, -T < data
name  ,Ane   ,Joane ,
adress  ,USA     ,England ,
mobile-number,12121212,234234,

$ rs -s, -C, -T < data | sort
adress  ,USA     ,England ,
mobile-number,12121212,234234,
name  ,Ane   ,Joane ,

$ rs -s, -C, -T < data | sort | rs -s, -C, -T
adress  ,mobile-number,name  ,
USA     ,12121212,Ane   ,
England ,234234,Joane ,

$ rs -s, -C, -T < data | sort | rs -s, -S' ' -T
adress         mobile-number  name  
USA            12121212       Ane   
England        234234         Joane
```

Finally:

```
$ rs -s, -C, -T < data | sort | rs -s, -S' ' -T | sed -e 's/ \([^ ]\)/,\1/g'
adress        ,mobile-number ,name  
USA           ,12121212      ,Ane   
England       ,234234        ,Joane
```

I did this on Ubuntu GNU/Linux, and first had to `sudo apt-get install rs`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @dta = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ",", strict => True)>>.trim;   \
         my $index = @dta.[0].pairs.sort(*.value).map: *.key;           \
         @dta.=map( *.[$index.cache]); csv(in => @dta, out => $*OUT);'  file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family that features high-level Unicode support. Above, the language is used at the command line in conjunction with Raku's `Text::CSV` module.

Sample Input:

```
name  ,adress  ,mobile-number
Ane   ,USA     ,12121212
Joane ,England ,234234
```

Sample Output:

```
adress,mobile-number,name
USA,12121212,Ane
England,234234,Joane
```

Briefly, data is read-in using the `csv(...)` method/function, whitespace is removed around entries using `trim`, and stored in  `@dta` array. An `$index` is generated from the `[0]` first row of `@dta` by converting entries to numbered `pairs`, `sort`ing by `value`, then getting the sorted numeric `key`s. Then `@dta` is `.=` over-written with `$index` re-ordered columns. Finally, a `csv` file is `out`put on `$*OUT` stdout.

Note: removing the call to `>>.trim` will return double-quoted column-values where entries contain trailing whitespace, in accordance with [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180). Reverse the column sort order by adding `.reverse` to the indexing code, as in `[$index.cache.reverse]`.

Sample Output without `>>.trim` and with `.reverse`:

```
"name  ",mobile-number,"adress  "
"Ane   ",12121212,"USA     "
"Joane ",234234,"England "
```

https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.md
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org